# ADO Connection to Access leaves .ldb file behind with Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass

Tags: ms-access, vba, locking, ado

I'm writing an MS Outlook (2003) macro which uses an ADO Connection to an Access DB (2003). I am opening a connection, getting some records into a Recordset, which I use to populate a grid (but not bind to). I then close the Recordset and Connection and set both to Nothing.

The process creates an instance of MSACCESS.EXE, and a .ldb file for the Access DB, both of which remain after I have closed the Connection, Recordset, Macro and Outlook itself. One or both of these remnants is preventing opening the Access DB until the MSACCESS.EXE process is manually killed and the .ldb file is deleted.

Similar posts say "close the connection" but that is not solving the problem.

Here's the VBA code:

```
Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass
Set db = New ADODB.Connection 'Declared at module level
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 'Declared at module level
Dim sSQL As String
 
sSQL = "SELECT Customers.ContactFirstName As Name, Customers.ContactLastName As Surname, Customers.EmailName AS Email, Customers.Address, Customers.Area, Customers.Town FROM qryCustomersWithEmail ORDER BY Customers.ContactLastName ASC"
db.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & "C:\My Documents\Tables.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
rs.Open sSQL, db, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then   
    'actions performed on recordset removed 
End If
rs.Close  
db.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
```

It's on Vista.

I'm doing this to provide my customer with an easy way to send bulk emails to everyone in his Access database. I tried by accessing Outlook from Access but the security "feature" of Outlook, which pops up a warning message for every email created, scuppered this approach.

**UPDATE**.

- I removed PopulateFlexGrid and the problem still occurred just for opening and closing the recordset. What I previously omitted from this sample, as I considered it irrelevant is that I wrapped the code with `Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass` at the start and `Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault` at the end.  I removed this and the problem no longer occurs. Stepping through I see MSACCESS.EXE start up in TM when I call `Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass`.
- I also tried a version where I used DAO instead of ADO, no other difference, and it works without creating .ldb or starting up an MSACCESS.exe. This works with the Screen.Mousepointer code in there.

Can anybody explain this?

Comment: Which versions of Outlook and Access?

Comment: Are you running this across a network? If so, check if there are any network concentrators or other devices that could be caching your ldb?

Comment: No it's on one machine no network involved

Comment: Now I'm thinking ADO connection pooling. I don't have time at the minute but can you try to look for a way to switch of ADO's default connection pools? That or use Access DAO, not ADO

Comment: I don't think you've included all the relevant code, as what you have included would not open Access, as OLEDB is entirely independent of the MS Access executable.

Comment: David, I have. It does. I know it shouldn't but it does.

Comment: Try this: find MSACCESS.EXE on your hard drive, and right click it and on the PROPERTIES sheet, choose SECURITY. Then for the EVERYONE group, choose DENY for READ. This will prevent anything from loading it. Then run your code.

Comment: I didn't include the Screen.MousePointer in my code sample. It seems that was causing the problem. I can't quite believe it.

Comment: I can't either. It's very weird.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this is that the reference to

```
Screen.MousePointer
```

which i'd omitted as irrelevant, is actually a member of Access. Hence when i call it MSACCESS starts up.

I should have used

```
Me.MousePointer = fmMousePointerHourGlass
```

So it's my fault for copying some code from Access VBA to Outlook VBA and expecting it to work the same. Apologies to all of you who spent time looking at this!

Comment: Kudos for figuring out *why* that was the solution. I thought it might be, but didn't think to fire up Outlook and Access to look at the object models.

Comment: BTW, I tend to automate all Office apps with late binding, so without a parent object, Screen.MousePointer in Outlook would not have compiled.

Answer (score 0):

What is the code of the function PopulateFlexGrid? Is it possible this is not closing the recordset passed to it?

Try removing this line and instead just looping through the code without doing anything and seeing if it still leaves the LDB. If it still leaves the LDB then the problem is not with the PopulateFlexGrid function

Comment: Thanks. Already done that. That's not the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with david saying there is something unclear here. Such a code cannot create an instance of Access or an .ldb file. This code could even run without Access being installed on the machine.

Could you open your recordset with a clientSide cursor? Using a serverSide cursor might cause the access file to be modified (not sure ...) in a way or another. To make sure that your next command does not interfeer in a way or another with access, you could even copy your record locally (to an xml file), close both records and connection, reopen the recordset with the xml file as datasource, and then populate your flexgrid.

By the way, and though it has nothing to do with your problem, it is usually preferable to split the object declaration to:

```
dim myObect as ADODB....
set myObject = New ADODB....
```

Comment: I didn't include the Screen.MousePointer in my code sample. It seems that was causing the problem. I can't quite believe it.

Comment: I also have some difficulties to believe this! Well anyway let's remember next time to (1) avoid using the screen Object from VB and (2) include all code, even if considered irrelevant, in the question!